# Autocad C# API Create new tool Palette

Tags: autocad-plugin

I am a new developer in `Autocad API` using `C#`. How could I create `Palette` and put some blocks inside it. After searching on internet I learned that I have to reference dll files from autocad

```
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
    using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows.ToolPalette;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.IO;
    using System;


    namespace Tool_Palette
{
    public class POS
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An AutoCAD Toolpalette can be created as described in [this blog post](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2009/10/adding-items-to-an-autocad-tool-palette-using-net.html) (with code) or [this blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/06/working-with-toolpalette-groups-using-net.html) with downloaded sample. Note each post shows a different approach.

You may also consider a WinForm User control as a PaletteSet object.

Answer (score 0):

First you create User Control (Window Form) and pass the user contol name in below function.

```
public void createPallete(UserControl userControl)
    {

       string palleteName = "My-Palette"; 

           PaletteSet myPaletteSet = new PaletteSet(palleteName, new Guid("68D660CE-F603-4978-93CB-AD3EEABC44D4"));

            myPaletteSet.Style = PaletteSetStyles.ShowAutoHideButton |
           PaletteSetStyles.ShowCloseButton |
           PaletteSetStyles.Snappable;

            myPaletteSet.Opacity = 100;

            myPaletteSet.Size = new Size(500, 400);
            myPaletteSet.MinimumSize = new Size(250, 200);

            myPaletteSet.Add(palleteName, userControl);
            myPaletteSet.Visible = true;
            userControl.AutoScroll = true;
    }
```